# Find highest common factor of two polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the highest common factor of the following expressions:

$6-8a-32a^2-18a^3$, $20-35a-95a^2-40a^3$

My attempt:

The polynomial on the left is divisible by $2$, the polynomial on the right is not divisble by $2$. Conversely the polynomial on the right is divisble by $5$ and not the one on the left. Hence simplify the polynomials, then toss out $2$ and $5$ knowing they cannot be in the final answer since we are finding the highest *common* factor.

\begin{array}{r|ll} 3-4a-16a^2-9a^3 & 4-7a-19a^2-8a^3   \end{array}

The lowest common multiple of $-9a^3$ and $-8a^3$ is $-72a^3$.

\begin{array}{|r|ll}  24-32a-128a^2-72a^3 & 36-63a-171a^2-72a^3 \\ 36-63a-171a^2-72a^3  \end{array}

Subtract the left hand side.

\begin{array}{r|ll} 43a^2+31a-12 & 36-63a-171a^2-72a^3   \end{array}

Now usually the next step is to multiply the polynomial on the left by $a$ and subtract on the right hand side, but the coefficients are a big problem here. $43$ is a prime number. I actually went ahead and found the lowest common multiple of $72$ and $43$ and kept calculating, but naturally the coefficients morphed into four places and I couldn't find the highest common factor. I don't believe the problem would require that kind of tedious calculation (and I still got it wrong anyway), so I feel I must've made a mistake somewhere. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

The answer is $1+a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're kind of drifting towards applying the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). In this case, though, the easiest way is probably to (1) prove that $1+a$ is a factor of both polynomials, (2) find the quotient of each polynomial divided by $1+a$, (3) find the GCD of the quotients.

If you do that here, then first you get that $9a^3+16a^2+4a-3 = (a+1)(9a^2+7a-1)$ and $8a^3+19a^2+7a-4 = (a+1)(8a^2+11a-4)$. Then we note that $(9a^2+7a-1)-(8a^2+11a-4) = a^2-4a+3 = (a-1)(a-3)$. Then it's pretty easy to spot that $a-1$ and $a-3$ are not factors of either polynomial, so only $a+1$ is the GCD.

Answer (score 1):

I tried continuing with the Euclidean Algorithm as you did and it's a complete monster.

But note by the rational root theorem (or just trial and error) that if $a=-1$ then $3-4a-16a^2-9a^3 =0$ and $4-7a-19a^2-8a^3=0$ (note if you subtract the even terms from the odd terms....) so $1+a$ must be a common factor of both.

$3-4a-16a^2-9a^3= 3 + 3a - 7a -7a^2 -9a^2 -9a^3 = (1+a)(3-7a-9a^2)$ and $4-7a-19a^2-8a^3= 4+4a -11a-11a^2 - 8a^2 - 8a^3 = (1+a)(4-11a-8a^2)$.

Now finding the greatest common factor of $3-7a-9a^2$ and $4-11a-8a^2$ will hopefully not as hard.

And actually as they are not constant multiples of each other if they *do* have a common factor it must be a polynomial of degree $1$ and if that were the case both of those would have a common solution.  But by rational root th. any root of $3-7a-9a^2$ must be $\pm 3,\pm 1,\pm \frac 13$ and and any root of $4-11a-8a^2$ must be $\pm 4,\pm 2,\pm 1, \pm \frac 12, \pm \frac 14$ and $\pm 1$ is not a root of either.

(And by the quadratic formula any solution to $3-7a -9a$ will be $\frac {-7 \pm \sqrt{49+108}}{18}$ which is not equal to any solution of $4-11a -8a^2$ which would be $\frac {-11 \pm \sqrt {121+128}}{16}$.)

But... maybe we should try E.A. just to be sure.

$(9a^2+7a-3)-(8a^2 +11a-4)=a^2 -4a + 1$

$(8a^2 + 11a -4)-8(a^2-4a+1)= 43a +4$

So $(43a^2 - 172a + 43)- (43a^2 + 4a^2) = -176a +43$ and

$(176a -43)- 4(43a-4) = 4a-27$ and

$(43a+4)- 11(4a-27)= -a+301$.

$(4a-27)-4(a-301)=$ an integer.  Thus $\gcd(3-7a-9a^2, 4-11a-8a^2)$ is an integer but it can't be any integer other than $\pm 1$.

So $1+a$ was the greatest common factor.